# How to retain focus on asp textbox or any html element) after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am creating website that have around 20~ or so asp:TextBox, all of them uses postback.
Issue I am having is that every time postback occurs textbox looses focus.
I have managed to retain focus on element that called postback, but that's not what I want, because by that time new box is focused.
I found few javascripts that supposed to retain focus after post back, but couldn't get single one of them work.
Honestly I don't know much about javascript, or proper procedure how to use , but it seems there is no way to achieve what I want with just html and c#.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group" id="vacancyTitleGroup" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Vacancy title  <b>*</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputTitle" placeholder="Vacancy title" OnTextChanged="inputTitle_TextChanged"  AutoPostBack="True" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="positionGroup" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputPosition" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Employee Position</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputPosition" placeholder="Employee Position" OnTextChanged="inputPosition_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="disciplineGroup" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputDiscipline" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Job Field/Discipline</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputDiscipline" placeholder="Job Field/Discipline" OnTextChanged="inputDiscipline_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="contractGroup" runat="server">
                    <label for="inputContract" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Contract Type <b>*</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputContract" placeholder="Contract Type" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="inputContract_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is some of html objects I want to retain focus on, I been stuck on this for half a day and if someone could give me rough guide how to retain focus after postback I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: are you familiar with `if(IsPostBack)` can you not do `SomeControl.Focus()` on the Page_Load` provided it's within the Postback portion of your conditional statement.. ? this code does nothing to help in your issue show your .cs codebehind as well I would do this also in a `__DoPostBack()` method as well if you're certain you want the focus to be set when firing / triggering particular events..

Comment: I'm curious why you postback to server on every TextChanged. It is really annoying for end user.

Comment: @Win for data validation, I could probably get away with only couple post backs, but I still would loose focus on those fields, why is it annoying for end user?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am familiar with IsPostBack. 
I have already attempted what you are suggesting, but I need to know current focus object and from what I understood there is no way to store current focus on server side, to restore it on postback. I can store focus on textChanged events, but those occur when object looses focus and stores object loosing focus and not new one that gain focus. End result : every time you tab to new textbox, autoPostBack occurs, and focus jumps to previous textbox, because it was one that stored focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to retain focus directly, but you can add a hidden field and post the active element into it:

Let's say the hidden field's id is "hdnSelectedField". An  should work.

With JQuery:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedField" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"  />
<script>
    // this creates an event that fires any time any "input" type element gets focus
    $("input").focus(function (e) {
        // get the target's type attribute (i.e. text, button, checkbox) and make sure it isn't submit
        if ($(e.target).attr('type') != 'submit') {
            // get the currently focused element's id & store it in the hidden field for postback processing
            var activeElem = document.activeElement.name;
            $("#hdnSelectedField").val(activeElem);
            // this just makes it obvious that something is happening. Set a <span> to the field's id
            $("#selectedElementName").html(activeElem);
        }
    });

</script>
```

on page load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            var fieldSelectedName = hdnSelectedField.Value;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldSelectedName))
                Page.FindControl(fieldSelectedName).Focus();
        }
    }
```

- edited to use the clientIDMode=static and work within an asp.net panel. Note that it now searches by name.

Comment: Java script can use onfocus html event, so we might get away without hidden fields, problem is I never wrote any javascript and dont know how to use it.

Comment: You could get away without hidden fields, but you'd still need to persist state through the postback, so some form of data holder is needed... Either add it to the querystring, use a cookie, or use a hidden field)

Comment: Hm, I keep getting nullreferenceexception, where should I put <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedField" runat="server" />
If I have many divs and many forms?  Like you can see in my example code, that is start of my page

Comment: You can put the hidden field anywhere within your main asp.net form. The position shouldn't matter, but I always tend to put them at the bottom. Can you post what you have in your main page? I might be able to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: Main page is just like any page without anything extra, Master page holds most of information. I have ziped up my project, if you have Visual studio, it might be easier just to look at it instead of posting bunch of code. If you dont have VS let me know, cheers for all your help.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7OaaychgL0_dHcwZTFZMExWTzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. Please make sure you put the jquery source <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> in your master page inside the <head> tag. You can also include it from the CDN (generally faster) if you want. The javascript I sent you requires the JQuery library

Comment: It is finally working! This was seriously driving me mad I even turned to ajax pageMethods, but couldnt get them to work either. Now I can finally focus on actual project instead of small things(not so small in the end ^^), thank you so much! You are the best!